# html form with select box cannot get value in another php page

Tags: php, html, forms

i have a php page called page1.php with this form

```
<form id="myForm" action="page2.php" method="post">
<label for="name">a label:</label><input type="submit" name="SubmitCar" value="Done" id="fbutton" /> <br />
<br />
<select name="selectCar">
<?php
session_start(); 

$user = "cardatabase";
$password = "";
$host = "";
$database = "my_cardatabase";
$connessione = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die( mysql_error() . " <br/> could not connect to server");
mysql_select_db($database, $connessione) or die( mysql_error() . " <br/> could not connect datbase");

$id = $_SESSION['myid'];

         $query = "select IDCar
                       from Car";

         $result = mysql_query($query, $connessione) or die(mysql_error());
         if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )  {
              $array = array();
              $i = 0;
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $array[$i] = $row['IDCar'];
                ++$i;
                }

              for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
                    echo "<option value='$array[$i]'>$array[$i]</option>";
                 }
            }
mysql_close();
?>
</select>
</form>
```

Simply fill the select box from DB. Now here's the problem. When i reach page2.php i need the value of the select box and i tried this

page2.php

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['selectCar'];
?>
```

But it's not working, so i tried to use sessions in this way

page1.php

```
</form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['SubmitCar'])){
    $_SESSION['idAuto'] = $_POST['selectCar'];
    }
    ?>
```

out of the form, but still not working. What can i do to get this value in page2.php??

Comment: use firebug (net tab) to see actual post data

Comment: Is the query working as supposed? When you load your main page do you see the options that you need? With which browser are you testing?

Comment: Safari and yes the box is completely filled! but when i try to echo the value in page2.php it's always blank

Comment: you need something like this https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html or firebug in firefox to see what you are posting to page2.php . You won't go far without these tools.

Comment: this seems to professional! this is just a homework! Anyway i came up with a simple workaround! i'll post in case someone will need

Comment: the second example with sessions won't work since you're posting selectCar to page2. This way you're never creating $_session['idauto']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple workaround for my problem. It might not be perfect but it works.

1. i deleted the `action="page2.php"` in the form of page1
2. in page1.php add this code outside the form

This will do the trick

```
        if(isset($_POST['SubmitCar'])){
        $_SESSION['idCar'] = $_POST['selectCar'];
        header('Location:page2.php');
        }
```

Comment: by the way i tried your code (i just removed the db part) and it worked perfectly...

Comment: what you mean?if you get out the db part you won't have the selected box filled

Comment: i used a dummy array instead: $array = array('a','b','c','d');
Then the rest was the same. After submitting i was able to echo the value in post['selectedCar']

Comment: So what you think the problem is?i mean with this workaround it worked, if it was a DB error i would have got blank too or not?i'm still new to html/php i'm going on tricking the compiler xD

Comment: Yes indeed, but the code you wrote seems to be supposed to work. Maybe is there anything strange in page2.php? If there is only a <?php echo $_POST['selectCar']; ?> there should be no problems. It doesn't make much sense to use sessions for your situation.

Comment: Oh well actually there's a lot of code in page2.php and was using session because i needed to echo the values all together not as soon as the page loads so i needed to maintain the values of the variables outside their scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code to build your `<option>` , and use `mysqli` when working with the database

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connessione, $query) or die(mysql_error());
         if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )  {
             $i=0;
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row$result)) {

                    echo "<option value='".$row[$i]."'>".$row[$i]."</option>";
                    $i++;
                 }
            }
```

Also, it's not indicated to have `mysql`  tables with names in `uppercase`, or fields with names in `uppercase`.

Comment: The select box is filled with the right data. I'll try this code but i don't think it's the solution

Comment: I also advice you that you use a name only with lowercase for input names

Answer (score 0):

### Page2.php

You forgot to echo it.

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['selectCar'];
echo $value;
?>
```

Comment: i echo it just i didn't pasted the code. But i echo a lot of value (some other sessions too) and this is the only blank